# Where is the option to correct for rolling shutter in ESRI's Drone2Map software?

Tags: unmanned-aerial-vehicle, photogrammetry, drone2map

I am looking for the proper way to enable a software fix for [rolling shutter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rolling_shutter) in Drone2Map.

Comment: I recall reading somewhere that Drone2Map uses a Pix4D engine.  I see Pix4D has rolling shutter correction. https://www.pix4d.com/blog/rolling-shutter-correction

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to ESRI the rolling shutter correction is applied automatically for images that need it.

Answer (score 2):

I have only seen references to a check-box in v1.3 documentation, but it wasn't there in the v1.3 instance I had access to.  It appeared to be in the attribute table for the photos.

Comment: Exactly. In the 1.3 docs it references the image properties window, but doesn't show what it looks like or how to access it. And in 2.0.1 there is no doc referencing it. I am stumped.